# less issue with calc function

Tags: magento2, less-css

I have written some code in less which is wrongly calculated its bug or something that I do wrong.

Orignal Code

```
 .main-class{
       .page-title-wrapper{
         width: calc( 100% - 45px );
       } 
 }
```

Expected result

```
 .main-class  .page-title-wrapper{
     width: calc( 100% - 45px );
 }
```

Result That I got

```
 .main-class  .page-title-wrapper{
     width: calc( 55%);
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **calc** as below.

```
.main-class{
       .page-title-wrapper{
         width: calc(~"100% - 45px");
       } 
 }
```

Comment: give me 15 min to accept answer, Your solution is working